# XML bomb (Entity Injection) is by default taken care in .Net 4.0 but not in .Net 3.5. How? What changed?

Tags: .net, xml, security, system.xml

Following code

```
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
            String xml = @"<!DOCTYPE lolz [" +
                    "<!ENTITY lol \"lol\">" +
                    "<!ENTITY lol2 \"&lol;&lol;&lol;&lol;&lol;&lol;&lol;&lol;&lol;&lol;\">" +
                    "<!ENTITY lol3 \"&lol2;&lol2;&lol2;&lol2;&lol2;&lol2;&lol2;&lol2;&lol2;&lol2;\">" +
                    "<!ENTITY lol4 \"&lol3;&lol3;&lol3;&lol3;&lol3;&lol3;&lol3;&lol3;&lol3;&lol3;\">" +
                    "<!ENTITY lol5 \"&lol4;&lol4;&lol4;&lol4;&lol4;&lol4;&lol4;&lol4;&lol4;&lol4;\">" +
                    "<!ENTITY lol6 \"&lol5;&lol5;&lol5;&lol5;&lol5;&lol5;&lol5;&lol5;&lol5;&lol5;\">" +
                    "<!ENTITY lol7 \"&lol6;&lol6;&lol6;&lol6;&lol6;&lol6;&lol6;&lol6;&lol6;&lol6;\">" +
                    "<!ENTITY lol8 \"&lol7;&lol7;&lol7;&lol7;&lol7;&lol7;&lol7;&lol7;&lol7;&lol7;\">" +
                    "<!ENTITY lol9 \"&lol8;&lol8;&lol8;&lol8;&lol8;&lol8;&lol8;&lol8;&lol8;&lol8;\">" +
                    "]>" +
                    "<lolz>&lol9;</lolz>";
            xdoc.LoadXml(xml);
```

**.Net 4.0**
This code will throw exception
*The input document has exceeded a limit set by **MaxCharactersFromEntities***

**.Net 2.0/3.5**
This code will **not throw** any exception and will keep on growing in XML until memory limit is reached

Can somebody explain the reason of this difference?

**Research done so far**
I disassembled System.Xml v2.0 and v4.0 and only change I saw was in method `RegisterConsumedCharacters` 
**v2.0 definition**

```
private void RegisterConsumedCharacters(long characters, bool inEntityReference)
{
    if (this.maxCharactersInDocument > 0L)
    {
        long num = this.charactersInDocument + characters;
        if (num < this.charactersInDocument)
        {
            this.ThrowWithoutLineInfo("XmlSerializeErrorDetails", new string[] { "MaxCharactersInDocument", "" });
        }
        else
        {
            this.charactersInDocument = num;
        }
        if (this.charactersInDocument > this.maxCharactersInDocument)
        {
            this.ThrowWithoutLineInfo("XmlSerializeErrorDetails", new string[] { "MaxCharactersInDocument", "" });
        }
    }
    if ((this.maxCharactersFromEntities > 0L) && inEntityReference)
    {
        long num2 = this.charactersFromEntities + characters;
        if (num2 < this.charactersFromEntities)
        {
            this.ThrowWithoutLineInfo("XmlSerializeErrorDetails", new string[] { "MaxCharactersFromEntities", "" });
        }
        else
        {
            this.charactersFromEntities = num2;
        }
        if ((this.charactersFromEntities > this.maxCharactersFromEntities) && XmlTextReaderSection.LimitCharactersFromEntities)
        {
            this.ThrowWithoutLineInfo("XmlSerializeErrorDetails", new string[] { "MaxCharactersFromEntities", "" });
        }
    }
}
```

**v4.0 definition**

```
private void RegisterConsumedCharacters(long characters, bool inEntityReference)
{
    if (this.maxCharactersInDocument > 0L)
    {
        long num = this.charactersInDocument + characters;
        if (num < this.charactersInDocument)
        {
            this.ThrowWithoutLineInfo("Xml_LimitExceeded", "MaxCharactersInDocument");
        }
        else
        {
            this.charactersInDocument = num;
        }
        if (this.charactersInDocument > this.maxCharactersInDocument)
        {
            this.ThrowWithoutLineInfo("Xml_LimitExceeded", "MaxCharactersInDocument");
        }
    }
    if ((this.maxCharactersFromEntities > 0L) && inEntityReference)
    {
        long num2 = this.charactersFromEntities + characters;
        if (num2 < this.charactersFromEntities)
        {
            this.ThrowWithoutLineInfo("Xml_LimitExceeded", "MaxCharactersFromEntities");
        }
        else
        {
            this.charactersFromEntities = num2;
        }
        if (this.charactersFromEntities > this.maxCharactersFromEntities)
        {
            this.ThrowWithoutLineInfo("Xml_LimitExceeded", "MaxCharactersFromEntities");
        }
    }
}
```

Only difference I see here is change in parameters of ThrowWithoutLineInfo and removal of XmlTextReaderSection.LimitCharactersFromEntities in v4.0, but I am not able to make much out of it and have hit a block here.

Comment: https://blogs.iis.net/nazim/archive/2013/03/13/safely-handling-untrusted-xml-server-side.aspx (not exactly specific for .net 3.5, but useful information)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default value for `XmlReaderSettings.MaxCharactersFromEntities` is 0 and means "no limit" as MSDN documentation says.

But there is a nasty trick not pointed out by the documentation, in .net 4 if you don't pass a `XmlReaderSettings` to your `XmlTextReader` then the limit is not set to 0 but to 10,000,000.

The relevant source code is here, even with a comment pointing out that this is a **breaking change**:
https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml/System/Xml/Core/XmlTextReaderImpl.cs,385

Comment: Just in time before the bounty was about to expire :)

Comment: The latest working link to reference source:
https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml/System/Xml/Core/XmlTextReaderImpl.cs,385

Comment: @mehmettkocc thanks for taking the time to look up the broken link. I updated my answer with the new link.

Answer (score 1):

So, you have found the culprit. In v2.0, `XmlTextReaderSection.LimitCharactersFromEntities` returns `false` so the exception is not thrown. In v4.0 `XmlTextReaderSection.LimitCharactersFromEntities` is omitted from the condition check so it throws the exception.

The question is what does `XmlTextReaderSection.LimitCharactersFromEntities` do and why does it return `false`? When we disassemble it, we see that it does the following:

```
    internal string LimitCharactersFromEntitiesString
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)base["limitCharactersFromEntities"];
        }
        set
        {
            base["limitCharactersFromEntities"] = value;
        }
    }

    private bool _LimitCharactersFromEntities
    {
        get
        {
            string limitCharactersFromEntitiesString = this.LimitCharactersFromEntitiesString;
            bool result = true;
            XmlConvert.TryToBoolean(limitCharactersFromEntitiesString, out result);
            return result;
        }
    }
    internal static bool LimitCharactersFromEntities
    {
        get
        {
            XmlTextReaderSection xmlTextReaderSection = ConfigurationManager.GetSection(XmlConfigurationString.XmlTextReaderSectionPath) as XmlTextReaderSection;
            return xmlTextReaderSection == null || xmlTextReaderSection._LimitCharactersFromEntities;
        }
    }
```

So `internal static bool`  function calls `private bool` one. `private bool` calls `internal string`. What `internal string` does is it tries to get the dictionary entry `"limitCharactersFromEntities"` from `ConfigurationSection` parent class. It probably returns null, so it cannot be casted to `bool` (check `XmlConvert.TryToBoolean` source) and in the end `XmlTextReaderSection.LimitCharactersFromEntities` returns false.

I checked further into the source code, but I could not find how or where `LimitCharactersFromEntities` configuration property is initialized in v2.0 (I couldn't check the whole .NET so what I did was `CTRL + F` to search for that string). However I've seen that `LimitCharactersFromEntities` is totally omitted in v4.0 and it doesn't exist as one of configuration property names in `XmlConfiguration.cs`.

So I guess we can conclude that in v2.0, that's a bug.

Note: I have totally no idea about XmlDocument and the System.Xml namespace at all. I've just tried to make some educated guesses reading source code.

Comment: Even I thought so but this isn't correct as, if you look closely if block which uses XmlTextReaderSection.LimitCharactersFromEntities is nested within another if block which only turn true for this.maxCharactersFromEntities > 0L and MaxCharactersFromEntities by default is 0

Comment: Then, it is about `XmlReaderSettings` and `XmlReader`, compare `XmlReaderSettings (v2.0)` and `XmlReaderSettings (v4.0)`. In v4.0 `this.maxCharactersFromEntities` is not initialized in `XmlReaderSettings.Reset` or anywhere in the class. In v2.0, it is initialized to 0. I couldn't find where it is initialized in v4.0 but I believe that it is not set to 0 unless you provide your own `XmlReaderSettings` instance and set it to 0 yourself. I know what documentation says, but it can be wrong.