# ServiceStack SOAP XmlException: The input document has exceeded a limit set by MaxCharactersInDocument

Tags: c#, soap, servicestack

As the title suggest, we are currently struggling with a ServiceStack v 4.0.44 SOAP service that throws the exception ([full stacktrace here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9ce3dcc3338dfcf5fc539b6a8864c7a7))

```
XmlException: The input document has exceeded a limit set by MaxCharactersInDocument.
... stacktrace cut down for brewity ... 
File "ServiceStack.Text.XmlSerializer" line 33 in Deserialize(System.String xml, System.Type type)
File "ServiceStack.Serialization.DataContractSerializer" line 34 in DeserializeFromString(System.String xml, System.Type type)
File "ServiceStack.Host.Handlers.SoapHandler" line 266 in ExecuteMessage(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message message, ServiceStack.RequestAttributes requestAttributes, ServiceStack.Web.IRequest httpReq, ServiceStack.Web.IResponse httpRes)
```

As far as I can read in other stackoverflow answers, this is a form of protection against XML bombs implemented in .net 4+ [ref1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14186824/xmlexception-the-input-document-has-exceeded-a-limit-set-by-maxcharactersfromen) [ref2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23096087/xml-bomb-entity-injection-is-by-default-taken-care-in-net-4-0-but-not-in-net)

Now my question is:
Is it possible to override this behavior in SS v4? We are only receiving requests from a trusted source (BizTalk) with data, so as far as I see, it is not a problem disabling this .net safeguard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [change the MaxCharactersInDocument](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/blob/cce255057d3b7da5862ec8f5d554479c90f120be/src/ServiceStack.Text/XmlSerializer.cs#L21) the ServiceStack XmlSerialier uses from its current default of:

```
XmlSerializer.Instance = new XmlSerializer(maxCharsInDocument: 1024 * 1024);
```